# Issue finding all variables in an Object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an Object called `Button_Objs`, its purpose is to hold all my `Button` Objects. I made a function in my `Button_Objs` which iterates through each of its variables. Here is where the issue is, I have a `if statement` that says: `if (i typeof Button){}`. I do this so it only selects the `Button` Objects that are stored.

Here is the JSFiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelMitchell/vcZTR/15/

```
var Button_Objs = function() {
    this.getButtons = function() {
        var i;
        for (i in this) {
            if (type of i == Button) { //PROBLEM, also does not work with instanceof.

                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += ( "button: " + i  + "<br />");

            }
        }
    };
};
```

I also tried `instanceof`, but alas it will not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i typeof Button` is invalid syntax and `type of i == Button` as well.

When you use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an object, the loop variable will hold the **name** of the property, not the value. You can use the name to get the value:

```
if(this[i] instanceof Button)
```

[Read more about the `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (I recommend to have a look at MDN to learn about JS basics).

---

Apart from this, I don't see why you need a constructor function to create a container for your buttons. You could just use a plain object:

```
var buttons = {};

// somewhere
buttons['button' + i] = new Button(...);
```

and then again use the `for...in` loop to iterate over the object.

And if you don't actually need the names (they just seem to be some sort of enumeration), why don't you use an array?

```
var buttons = [];

// somewhere
buttons.push(new Button(...));
```

and then use a `for` loop to iterate over all buttons. You would not even have to test for their type.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was just returning the name. Thanks, and about the JSFiddle, I dunno what happened, I had it proper Syntax and then I goofed it all :/

Comment: Hmm, if I wanted that `for... in` loop to do stuff for that Object, why should I keep it outside of it?

Comment: I meant that you don't need `Button_Objs` and a method to extract the list of buttons if you could just directly use an array to achieve the same with less code. Just a suggestion.